# Validation returning " Undefined index"

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have a form that saves an `ad` and this `ad` have a lot of informations and the visual of this `ad` could be an `image` or a `video`. I have a `combo box` with two values, `image (value 0)` and `video (value 1)`. This `0 and 1` is not boolean, is just the code, if someday I have a third type it will be `2`...

The issue is, on validation I can only allow `image_file` for being `empty` if this combobox have the value `1 (video)`, so I did it:

```
    $validator
        ->allowEmpty('image_file', function($context){
            if ($context['data']['type'] == 1) { //This is the 142 Line, Type is the combobox.
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: type [APP/Model\Table\AdsTable.php, line 142]
```

The strange is, I'm sure `type` field exists, if I do it:

```
    $validator
        ->allowEmpty('image_file', function($context){
            echo $context['data']['type']; // Echo the type field value.
            if ($context['data']['type'] == 1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
```

I can get the `type` value at `echo`, so that proves the field exists.

**Update:**

If I do this:

```
$validator
    ->allowEmpty('image_file', function($context){
        print_r($context['data']);

        if ($context['data']['type'] == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Right over the field I got an `empty array` and the `undefined index`, The issue is, the validation is being fired when the field is being created at form creation instead when the form is posted so the `context` actually does't exists.

I'm sure that's the issue but have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: You really get `0` and `1` by echoing `type`?

Comment: just modify you condition if(isset($context['data']['type']) && $context['data']['type'] == 1), and check

Comment: Guys look at my update please

Comment: There is a typo in your update... is this copied directly from your code?  "imagem_file" looks like it should be "image_file" ?

Comment: I just translate the fields name for a better understanding, this is not the issue. Please look at my new update.. I got the problem but I dont know solve this.

Comment: Guys actually I can solve this testing `isset($context['data']['type'])` before, but.. is right this logic being fired at field creation?

Comment: then solution is either make those fields required, or put your validator check condition in an isset condition as i saidpreviously.